# WSO2 Alternative

Tags: wso2

Is there any alternative for WSO2?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

not realy, but some products close to (commercial open source only)

- Mule ESB...
- Sopera (bought by talend, last month)
- Fuse ESB...

as far as I know the SOA-World, WSO2 products are unique in terms of

- complete Open Source infrastructure for SOA + cloud PaaS
- all products licensed under Apache Software License
- not only libraries, but web-GUI, DEV-Tools and OSGi-P2 repositories
- you can follow the public mailing-lists (tip: carbon-dev and architecture)
- conforms to a lot of WS-standards

some drawbacks

- very active development at WSO2, not easy to follow
- some products in a early stage

Comment: more drawbacks:
- very HARD to test
- not easy unit testing and mocking services

Answer (score 26):

When you look for "WSO2 Alternative" you need to be precise on which space of WSO2 that you are looking for alternatives.

WSO2 has a complete enterprise middleware stack as well as the same middleware platform as a cloud computing platform as a service offering.

The middleware platform stack, include products such as

- Application Server
- ESB
- Business Process Server
- and more...

There are loads of Apache projects that the WSO2 products are based on, such as Apache Axis2, Apache Synapse, Apache Tomcat, Apache ODE, Apache Rampart and the like. 
One can use these base projects of the WSO2 and use those as alternatives to achieve various aspects of the platform.

You can also use the Eclipse Equinox and P2 projects, used as the base OSGi platform to facilitate the plug and play architecture of WSO2 Carbon base platform.

Note that, all of the products from WSO2 come with Apache 2.0 license.

If you are looking for alternatives other than Apache compatible license, in open source space, you can look for individual products aspects like ESB or BPEL or Application Server. 
Some examples:

- ESB alternatives: FUSE, Mule
- BPEL : Intalio BPM Server

If you are looking for [proprietary alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware#Organizations) to WSO2 middleware stack you need to look for...
 - IBM 
 - Oracle
 - Redhat

In the cloud space, a good comparison of the cloud Java Platform as a Service on WSO2 offerings and others can be found at: http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/08/comparison-wso2-stratos-other-paas-offerings
That article compares some of the alternatives such as

- Google App Engine
- Amazon Beanstalk
- CloudBee's Run@Cloud

with WSO2 StratosLive.

Answer (score 3):

For which of the WSO2 products are looking for an alternative? WSO2 has a lot of products (ESB, Business Process Server, Governance Registry, Identity Server, Business Rules Server, etc.). Depending on what product / functional requirements you're asking for, there may be a lot of solutions.

Some open source ESBs are:

- FUSE (based on Apache Service Mix)
- OpenESB / Glassfish ESB (Sun -> Oracle -> Independent)
- Mule
- Petals
- UltraESB
- Membrane ESB (no really ESB, but may satify your needs)
  ...

Some non-open source:

- Oracle ESB
- Bea AquaLogic
- Microsoft BizTalk Server
  ...

Some Business Process Servers:

- Intalio BPM Server
- Adeptia
- BizAgi
- Saavion
- ActiveVOS
- Activiti

...

Comment: WSO2 approach is more like a complete SOA solution. I don't see its products seperately, therefore i was looking for a complete SOA framework as WSO2 do.

Comment: You can easily create a complete framework in a one product, by installing the necessary features via the Component Manager found in any WSO2 product. If you downloaded WSO2 AppServer, you can add features of WSO2 ESB, WSO2 Governance Registry etc via this pretty easily.
So, you CAN have a complete SOA framework in one product with WSO2.

Answer (score 1):

Mule ESB is now available as part of a true cloud iPAAS (integration PAAS) called Mule iON.

Mule ESB has a very strong developer community and over 2500 production deployments. The community distro is actively developed and maintained.