# Transaction services in Mule ESB or WSO2 ESB

Tags: mule, esb, wso2-esb

I'm try to develop transaction service. So I want to check balance and continue transaction in one service call (balance checking and paying services are two separate services). I think, I must use one of Enterprise Service Bus(ESB) to overcome this. What is the better ESB(WSO2 esb or Mule esb)?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033891/wso2-alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of type of question depends on user's experience and expertise over the tools.
You can find may links on internet comparing these tools like https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/36781-178821575

Comment: thanks. it was helpful discussion to understand real different between WSO2 esb and mule.